# need help in xcode swift uiscrollview height destination

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, xcode7

What if I want to scroll down to a certain page and make a bookmark section for it too, my height of viewcontroller is 5000 and width is normal of a 4.7 screen, but don't know how to scroll to the certain page I want and a bookmark so the user can go there faster. help!

I am using swift

Comment: Please add some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(x, y)
```

Comment: What if i tap on a UIButton and i want to make it go to certain x and y spot,     like my button name is "Test" and when i click "Test" it goes to the x and y. This would help alot if you can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  
    ScrollView.contentSize.height = 5000
   ScrollView.contentSize.width = 375
        
        
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

Comment: so far thats what i have done, can you explain what you mean by that? i made it a iboutlet on viewcontroller and named it to test, when i click it i want it to scoll auto to that spot on the page, which my scollview is 5000 in hieght

Comment: have you connected button from storyboard to view controller using @IBAction?

Comment: can you help still?  How do i make it so that i can do     scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(x, y)
to the button

Comment: do you mean bringing button to x,y position? you can use button.origin.frame.x and y

Answer (score 1):

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(x, y), animated: true)
```

or

```
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(x, y, w, h), animated: true)
```

Comment: 1) need an action in viewcontroller class @IBAction
2) then need and IBOutlet for scrollview
3) connect IBAction and IBOutlet with storyboard 
4) inside IBAction write above code "scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(x, y, w, h), animated: true)"

Comment: Thanks i'll give it a try!